# Is There A Way To Pass A Key And An Object As Return Value In Micronaut With Kafka

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, micronaut

```
@Topic("my-producer-topic")
@SendTo("my-consumer-topic")
fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String, value: String?): FpcPackProd {
    var objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    var myClassJsonString = value.toString()
    var myClass: myClass = objectMapper.readValue(myClassJsonString,
            myClass::class.java)

    var logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Consumer Logger")
    logger.info("Consumed Data: {}", myClass)

    return myClass
}

companion object {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Consumer Logger")
}}       data class myClass (var myData: String? = null, var mySecData: String? = null)
```

I am currently only returning a class and I would to return the data class and the myData value as the kafka i.e return "sendKeyValue(myClass.myData, myClass)". Is there a way to do so with micronaut, kafka and kotlin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to specify the key when sending to a topic via @SendTo. You can see in the source code it just takes the key from the consumed Record https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/blob/319c7b1fe6758922559c3038a930ae88ba664e2d/kafka/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/processor/KafkaConsumerProcessor.java#L623.

You'll need to create a kafka client like below:

```
@KafkaClient
interface MyProducer {
    @Topic("my-consumer-topic")
    fun sendProduct(@KafkaKey key: String?, value: myClass?)
}
```

And then inject it into your consumer:

```
@KafkaListener
class MyConsumer {

    @Inject
    lateinit var myProducer: MyProducer

    @Topic("my-producer-topic")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String, value: String?) {
        var objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()

        var myClassJsonString = value.toString()
        var myClass: myClass = objectMapper.readValue(myClassJsonString,
                myClass::class.java)

        var logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Consumer Logger")
        logger.info("Consumed Data: {}", myClass)

        myProducer.send(myClass.myData, myClass)
    }

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Consumer Logger")
    }
}
data class myClass (var myData: String? = null, var mySecData: String? = null)
```